# What's wrong with closing applications on Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile

As far as I can tell, this annoys the crap out of people that *do notice* and (at max) gives no real benefit to people who *don't notice*:

Why did Microsoft decide to make the "X" on Windows Mobile (or CE before that) not *close*, but only *hide* the application, and thus keep cluttering up your memory?

- WM wants you to go to the Control
  Panel -> Memory and "Do you really
  want to" shut down the app.
- Pretty much every WM application I've
  seen that did *not* come from
  Microsoft has a "Quit" menu choice.
- The number of task managers out there
  that *let you quit programs* is
  larger than the count of emails from
  African bank managers that want me to
  take care of some millions of bucks
  that belonged to a deceased customer
  of theirs.
- My new HTC even comes with a
  close-able (not closeable, though)
  task manager pre-installed.

But still today, Word Mobile just wants to hide, not be closed.

I don't want to get a "That's M$hit, get used to it" answer; I really want to know:

What in the world is the reason for this decision, and even more, for still sticking with it?

Comment: FWIW, I've recently noticed many Microsoft applications have a "Quit" or "Exit" menu item now: IE Mobile (on WinMo 6.5), Facebook, Marketplace to name a few.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Windows Mobile team's blog:

[The Emperor Has No Close](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2006/10/05/The-Emperor-Has-No-Close.aspx)

In summary of the above article, Windows Mobile's base philosophy is that users on a mobile platform shouldn't be expected to have to manage the memory. So it will close applications to free memory when needed. The `X` button was designed as a "I've finished with this" button, but the choice of `X` obviously implies close.

Comment: That's quite a nice read, I actually liked it (the title is *awesome*!). While I don't totally agree with the reasoning, the whole thing is starting to make sense. Thanks.

Comment: It is still really darn annoying!  Of all the mobile OS's I have used so far, WM is really low on the list for me.

Comment: I hear you, geoffc, but at least it runs Python and doesn't put me in a sandbox :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you install [Pocket Plus](http://www.spbsoftware.com/pocketpc-software/pocketplus/) from SpbSoftware, you can make it so the close button actually works as a close. I've found it handy.

The software also adds swipe-to-scroll and tab-browsing to Pocket IE.